# Unable to view already created APIs in WSO2 APIM Publisher and Store but able to see them under subscriptions

Tags: solr, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I had created few APIs earlier and published the same through API Publisher in WSO2 API Manager(APIM) , I was able to view them in Publisher Dashboard and Store Dashboard as well.I had subscribed them and was able to use the APIs.

Recently, I am unable to see any of those created APIs in Publisher Dashboard or Store Dashboard as well in API Manager.

I have not made any changes to configuration of API Manager.

I tried to publish APIs using REST APIs exposed by WSO2 APIM but I got following error message.

Publisher Response :

```
{
   "error" : true, 
   "message" : "Failed to change the life cycle status : An exception occurred   while executing handler chain. SolrCore 'registry-indexing' is not available due to init failure: Error opening new searcher"

}
```

I have checked Thrift ports (Both are on 10397 and I have tried disabling them too as per other posts on stack overflow).

I have checked API Gateway credentials it is as they were by default i.e

```
<APIGateway>
        <!-- The environments to which an API will be published -->
        <Environments>
            <!-- Environments can be of different types. Allowed values are 'hybrid', 'production' and 'sandbox'.
                 An API deployed on a 'production' type gateway will only support production keys
                 An API deployed on a 'sandbox' type gateway will only support sandbox keys
                 An API deployed on a 'hybrid' type gateway will support both production and sandbox keys. -->
            <!-- api-console element specifies whether the environment should be listed in API Console or not -->
            <Environment type="hybrid" api-console="true">
                <Name>Production and Sandbox</Name>
                <Description>This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic.</Description>
                <!-- Server URL of the API gateway -->
                <ServerURL>https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}${carbon.context}services/</ServerURL>
                <!-- Admin username for the API gateway. -->
                <Username>${admin.username}</Username>
                <!-- Admin password for the API gateway.-->
                <Password>${admin.password}</Password>
                <!-- Endpoint URLs for the APIs hosted in this API gateway.-->
                <GatewayEndpoint>http://${carbon.local.ip}:${http.nio.port},https://${carbon.local.ip}:${https.nio.port}</GatewayEndpoint>
            </Environment>
        </Environments>
    </APIGateway>
```

I am unable to create new APIs as well since it seems there is some problem with Registry.

P.S : It also gives message that MQTT is disabled

Can anyone please help out ?

Please check screenshots for more clarity

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WSO2 API Manager issues with solr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42646421/wso2-api-manager-issues-with-solr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an indexing issue. Shall we try what is mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42646742/3176125). This will reindex the APIs.