# wso2-am v210 published APIS are not shown in Publisher and Store

Tags: java, solr, store, wso2-api-manager, publisher

i use wso2-am v210 at a linux system with default h2 database.
I have pulished APIS sucessfully. If i change to publisher or store the list of APIs is empty. The only you see is "No APIs published yet".
If i change to carbon management console i could see my APIs in:

Resources/Browse/_system/apimgt/applicationdata/provider/{user}

What could i do to let the APIs be shown in Store and Publisher?

From Webapp-Start there are following Errors logged:

> [2017-04-05 08:21:48,324]-[INFO
>   ]-[org.apache.solr.core.SolrXmlConfig]-[]-[]-[]-[]-[Loading container
>   configuration from /myinstanz/repository/conf/solr/solr.xml]
>   [2017-04-05
>   08:21:48,365]-[DEBUG]-[org.apache.solr.core.Config]-[]-[]-[]-[]-[null
>   missing optional solr/@coreLoadThreads] [2017-04-05
>   08:21:48,365]-[DEBUG]-[org.apache.solr.core.Config]-[]-[]-[]-[]-[null
>   missing optional solr/@persistent] [2017-04-05
>   08:21:48,365]-[DEBUG]-[org.apache.solr.core.Config]-[]-[]-[]-[]-[null
>   missing optional solr/@sharedLib] [2017-04-05
>   08:21:48,365]-[DEBUG]-[org.apache.solr.core.Config]-[]-[]-[]-[]-[null
>   missing optional solr/@zkHost] [2017-04-05
>   08:21:48,366]-[DEBUG]-[org.apache.solr.core.Config]-[]-[]-[]-[]-[null
>   missing optional solr/cores] [2017-04-05 08:21:48,415]-[INFO
>   ]-[org.apache.solr.core.CoresLocator]-[]-[]-[]-[]-[Config-defined core
>   root directory: /myinstanz/repository/conf/solr] [2017-04-05
>   08:21:48,439]-[INFO
>   ]-[org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer]-[]-[]-[]-[]-[New CoreContainer
>   169912266] [2017-04-05 08:21:48,440]-[INFO
>   ]-[org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer]-[]-[]-[]-[]-[Loading cores into
>   CoreContainer [instanceDir=/myinstanz/repository/conf/solr/]]
>   [2017-04-05 08:21:48,440]-[INFO
>   ]-[org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer]-[]-[]-[]-[]-[loading shared
>   library: /myinstanz/repository/conf/solr/lib] [2017-04-05
>   08:21:48,440]-[WARN
>   ]-[org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader]-[]-[]-[]-[]-[Can't find
>   (or read) directory to add to classloader: lib (resolved as:
>   /myinstanz/repository/conf/solr/lib).] [2017-04-05
>   08:21:48,450]-[ERROR]-[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject]-[]-[]-[]-[]-[Error
>   while getting API Information] org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
>   Error instantiating shardHandlerFactory class
>   [HttpShardHandlerFactory]: Error loading class
>   'HttpShardHandlerFactory'          at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.component.ShardHandlerFactory.newInstance(ShardHandlerFactory.java:53)
>          at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:328)
>          at
>   org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient.(SolrClient.java:131)          at
>   org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient.getInstance(SolrClient.java:142)
>          at
>   org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.service.ContentBasedSearchService.searchContentInternal(ContentBasedSearchService.java:156)
>
> ...
>
> [2017-04-05 08:21:48,927]-[WARN
>   ]-[org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader]-[]-[]-[]-[]-[Can't find
>   (or read) directory to add to classloader: lib (resolved as:
>   /myinstanz/repository/conf/solr/lib).] [2017-04-05
>   08:21:48,930]-[ERROR]-[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject]-[]-[]-[]-[]-[Error
>   while getting API tags] org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error
>   instantiating shardHandlerFactory class [HttpShardHandlerFactory]:
>   Error loading class 'HttpShardHandlerFactory'          at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.component.ShardHandlerFactory.newInstance(ShardHandlerFactory.java:53)
>          at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:328)
>          at
>   org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient.(SolrClient.java:131)
>
> ...
>
> [2017-04-05 08:22:09,068]-[INFO
>   ]-[org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer]-[]-[]-[]-[]-[loading shared
>   library: /myinstanz/repository/conf/solr/lib] [2017-04-05
>   08:22:09,068]-[WARN
>   ]-[org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader]-[]-[]-[]-[]-[Can't find
>   (or read) directory to add to classloader: lib (resolved as:
>   /myinstanz/repository/conf/solr/lib).] [2017-04-05
>   08:22:09,075]-[ERROR]-[JAGGERY.site.pages.index:jag]-[]-[]-[]-[]-[org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
>   Error instantiating shardHandlerFactory class
>   [HttpShardHandlerFactory]: Error loading class
>   'HttpShardHandlerFactory'] [2017-04-05
>   08:22:09,077]-[ERROR]-[org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager]-[]-[]-[]-[]-[org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError:
>   TypeError: Cannot read property "apis" from null
>   (/publisher/site/blocks/listing/block.jag#40)]
>   org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException:
>   org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property
>   "apis" from null (/publisher/site/blocks/listing/block.jag#40)         at
>   org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571)
>          at
>   org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
>          at
>   org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:588)
>          at
>   org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
>
> ...
>
> [2017-04-05 08:22:26,883]-[WARN
>   ]-[org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader]-[]-[]-[]-[]-[Can't find
>   (or read) directory to add to classloader: lib (resolved as:
>   /myinstanz/repository/conf/solr/lib).] [2017-04-05
>   08:22:26,887]-[ERROR]-[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject]-[]-[]-[]-[]-[Error
>   while getting API Information] org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
>   Error instantiating shardHandlerFactory class
>   [HttpShardHandlerFactory]: Error loading class
>   'HttpShardHandlerFactory'          at
>   org.apache.solr.handler.component.ShardHandlerFactory.newInstance(ShardHandlerFactory.java:53)
>          at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:328)
>          at
>   org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient.(SolrClient.java:131)          at
>   org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient.getInstance(SolrClient.java:142)

I tried it local and everything worked fine.

Please, could you help me?

Thank you.
Greets

Comment: Can u try http://stackoverflow.com/a/42646742/3176125?

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I saw the Answer another time and tried it, but the deployment doesn't work and i made the wrong Turn. Sorry to cause work.