# Migrating WSO2 api manager databases

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to migarte my API from one environment to another environment by copying H2 databases from wso2am-2.1.0/repository/database.

I know there is an utility for import/export but I have a lot of API and this utility is only processing by one API.
After copying databases , my APIs and tags are not shown in the store/publisher dashboard.
But if I check applications-->subscriptions, I can see theses API.
Any explication about this behaviour please?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, WSO2 does not recommend to run production in H2 database. I hope this is a testing/ try out scenario. When you are running in production please use a production-ready databases such as oracle, mysql, mssql, etc.

The issue here is things you have listed as missing comes from the indexing. In your case, if there are lots of APIs, it would take time to index. WSO2 uses solr to index resources. If you copy the solr directory which resides in the WSO2 server folder to the new environment would work. Before replacing the folder please delete the complete folder in the new environment.

If this is not working you can re-index resources by following - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42646742/3176125.

When you are moving from one environment to another you need to copy the content which resides in the /repository/deployment/server/ folder. It contains synapse configs of the APIs, custom sequences, etc.