# API Publisher and Store not displaying API

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

My wso2registry was pointing to wso2carbon datasource which was configured with h2 db. Other db were configured with mysql. I was getting errors that there are some locks on h2 db and my wso2 server was not starting up .I changed the wso2carbon to point to  mysql regdb endpoint. The server started after that. Now the api created earlier in the publisher console are not visible. The api are also not showing up in the store even though the store says that it is listing some 18 apis. If i create the apis again I get a duplicate error.
I tried to point the wso2carbon datasource back to the same h2 db but still the publisher and store apis do not come up.
Is there a way I can clean up the apis so that I can recreate them with regdb  configured with mysql db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see your APIs with H2 database again, reindex the registry.

1. Change the `<lastAccessTimeLocation>` element in the `<APIM_HOME>/repository/conf/registry.xml` file in the Store/Publisher node. For example, change the `/_system/local/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.registry/indexing/lastaccesstime` registry path to `/_system/local/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.registry/indexing/lastaccesstime_1`.
2. Restart the server. After a few seconds, it should re-index the APIs.

Comment: I tried the change and restarted the server . But still the store says listing 0-18 apis while it is listing none. I created a new one . it is just listing that saying 0-19 apis.

Comment: in casewe are unable to fix  and a clean up needs to be done to recreate the apis fresh, what should the steps to be followed when a set up already exists . Should we recreate the mysql databases again. I checked the tables in apimgmt and regdb and they contain api specific data Do we also need to do  changes on the installation.i.e delete some files

Comment: You can delete the APIs you created (only) in `repository/deployments/server/synapse/default/api/` dir.

Comment: the api records are present in the apimgt db tables. I tried deleting one api from this path but it does not change the table level entries. So when i recreate the same api it tells it is duplicate

Comment: what i said was in addition to having new databases.

Comment: After recreating databases,now I am able to add APIs again and they are getting listed on the store portal. The only discrepancy is on the store portal, the first page displays API count as 0 - 12 of 21 APIs when the number of apis published to store are only 13.

Comment: do you have multiples API versions?

Comment: no.somehow seems that the api count counter is not reset even after clearing all apis from the database and the default/api path.

Comment: hope you cleaned all databases. these counts are coming from registry db.

Comment: Yes. Infact I dropped all databases and created them fresh.

Answer (score 0):

The existing solution given by Bee below did not work for me. Because the file was overwritten with default values every time I restarted my server.
Instead I did this.

```
Go to your Api manager management console 
> Resources 
> Browse 
> Location 
> /_system/local/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.registry/indexing
```

Or you can go directly to this [url](https://%3CDomain%3E/carbon/resources/resource.jsp?region=region3&item=resource_browser_menu&path=/_system/local/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.registry/indexing&screenWidth=1920)
Here you just need to rename it lastaccesstime -> lastaccesstime_old

Screenshot : [image: Screenshot of api mgr mgmt console]