# Error occurred when publish to gateway Production and Sandbox

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am able to create a new API, I can publish it, and it will appear in the API Store. However, I am unable to publish to gateway "Production and Sandbox", as I get the following error message:

"Failed to Publish Environments
Production and Sandbox:Error while publishing API to the Gateway. Error while publishing API to the Gateway. No API exists by the name: apicreator--TestApi:v1.0.0"

And checking in wso2carbon.log, this is the error log:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-25 10:24:08,212] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIGatewayManager} -  Error occurred when publish to gateway Production and Sandbox {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIGatewayManager}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while publishing API to the Gateway. Error while publishing API to the Gateway. No API exists by the name: apicreator--TestAPI:v1.0.0
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIGatewayAdminClient.addApi(APIGatewayAdminClient.java:87)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIGatewayManager.publishToGateway(APIGatewayManager.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.publishToGateway(APIProviderImpl.java:1519)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.updateAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:925)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.manageAPI(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:72)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.saveAPI(APIProviderHostObject.java:1061)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.jsFunction_manageAPI(APIProviderHostObject.java:539)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c4._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag:9)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c4.call(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_43(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:136)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_3(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag:329)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag:21)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:588)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while publishing API to the Gateway. No API exists by the name: apicreator--TestAPI:v1.0.0
        at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:370)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:445)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.stub.APIGatewayAdminStub.addApi(APIGatewayAdminStub.java:4044)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIGatewayAdminClient.addApi(APIGatewayAdminClient.java:84)
        ... 77 more
```

Comment: The question is a bit confusing. Are you saying that when you publish, you can see the API in the store, but you see this error in the logs? and is this a multi-node setup? please explain the deployment.

Comment: Hi @Bee, I can publish, only if I do not select a gateway. When I select "Production and Sandbox" gateway, I can't publish and get these errors. It is not multi-node setup

Comment: I think there should be another error trace. Can you double check?

Comment: I get the same error on an environment. I tried to delete the API and add it again with the same name, but without results, the API gets the CREATED status and can not be published. If I add an API with another name it's ok.
Errors are the following:

-  ERROR - APIGatewayManager Error occurred when publish to gateway Production and Sandbox
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while publishing API to the Gateway. Error while publishing API to the Gateway. No API exists by the name: admin--Test...

Comment: APIM v2.6.0. Errors are the following: 
- Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while publishing API to the Gateway. No API exists by the name: admin--Test:v1.0.0 ...
- ERROR -APIExecutor Failed to publish service gateway while executing APIExecutor. 
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.FaultGatewaysException
- ERROR -ApiMgtDAO Unable to find the API: admin-Test-1.0.0 in the database
- ERROR -add:jag org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Unable to find the API: admin-Test-1.0.0 in the database (/publisher/modules/api/add.jag#134)

Answer (score 0):

This link helped me: [WSO2 API Manager issues with solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42646421/wso2-api-manager-issues-with-solr).

1. Backup the solr folder which resides in /solr and remove from API Manager home location.
2. Open /repository/conf/registry.xml
3. Under indexingConfiguration tag there is a value called lastAccessTimeLocation.

Default value is

> /_system/local/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.registry/indexing/lastaccesstime

Change that value to

> /_system/local/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.registry/indexing/lastaccesstime1

4. Start the server.
5. Wait about 2 minutes for indexing.
6. Recheck the creation of the API.

Comment: This solution did not work for me because my file was keep overwritten with default values. But the solution on this post did work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77444043/2683452