# Enable second wso2 Publisher/Store instance

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I have WSO2 API MAnager 2.6.0 setup with 2 instances running for a while. 
Instance one - Traffic Manager, Store, Publisher, Key Manager 
Instance two - gateway 
 
For some reasons I need to start using Store and Publisher on the gateway node for one particular case. According to manuals, there should not be any issues with that since I haven't done optimization and profile startup. just like HA setup, but without huge traffic on second gateway Store/Publisher. 
The issue is, whet I open https://Instance two:9444/store (offset+1 on that server) I see only 2 APIs out of 7 published on Instance one. 
The DB datasources are noted in config as well as synapse files are on same server. At Instance two startup logs I see that APIs are initialized.. 
Any ideas?

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-08-20 09:53:56,759]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker} -  Endpoint : URApiProxy--v2.0.0_APIproductionEndpoint was added to the Synapse configuration successfully {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker}
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-08-20 09:53:56,760]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker} -  Endpoint : URApiProxy--v2.0.0_APIsandboxEndpoint was added to the Synapse configuration successfully {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker}
```

further

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-08-20 09:53:57,528]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker} -  API : admin--URApiProxy:v2.0.0 was added to the Synapse configuration successfully {org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker}
```

further

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-08-20 09:54:20,692]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.rest.API} -  Initializing API: admin--URApiProxy:v2.0.0 {org.apache.synapse.rest.API}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the same configs in registry.xml in instance 2 according to instance 1. Optionally you can try reindexing the server. Please refer [WSO2 API Manager issues with solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42646421/wso2-api-manager-issues-with-solr/42646742#42646742)

Comment: Well, this worked. Looks like I have to set up industry-standard RDBMS for registry as well and set it in both nodes. So far I hav no regdb in place but seems that it will be needed to avoid manual reindexing.