# WSO2 - AM Store paging issues

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

We have two environments(prep and prod). Both have WSO2 AM and WSO2 IS-KM.

We installed those on pre-production and configured on AM store more than 30 APIs. WSO2AM is paging fine the APIs (actually there are 3 pages).

To deploy it faster on production we cloned the VMs running WSO2 AM and WSO2 IS and we created new databases for production environment. We only added 2 APIs on this environment, and all is going quite good. But for some reasons Store is paging APIs and considering that there are still 30 APIs.

Basically it is displaying 3 pages for 2 APIs that can be displayed on one single page.

Do you have some idea why it is happening? Maybe some cached file on file system that was copied during the clone?

Comment: what's your APIM version?

Comment: In latest version after 2.1.0, AFAIK we have a property called skipCache in registry .xml which fetches API data from database directly without going via cache (Solr). When you are copying the pack to other environment, you may have copied solr directory of the previous pack which resides in carbon home location. If this is an older version, you can reindex and see - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42646742/3176125\

Comment: Hello! We have installed version 2.6 and property skipCache is set on true in registry.xml file.
I restarted it several times but the issue persists. Something more that can help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I executed the steps described by Pubci and it works like a charm. I removed the solr directory and restart wso2.
Now all is working fine.