# One API is missing (not being displayed) from node-2 publisher page in wso2 APIM - HA

Tags: api, wso2-api-manager, wso2

I have 2 nodes running in HA mode having common databases and artifacts synchronised. First node shows all the APIs (total-5) but second node shows only 4 ... one API is not being displayed on publisher page of second node. How should I resolve this issue what should I check here ? Is there any back-end directories where publisher stores data of this API ?

Comment: Is this APIM 3.2.0?

Comment: You can try solr indexing - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42646421/wso2-api-manager-issues-with-solr/42646742#42646742

Comment: @RrR- yes it is 3.2.0

Comment: I tried solr indexing but did not work, still missing that one API.